# Is DTrace as useful in Dynamic and Runtime languesg like Python and Java?

Tags: debugging, native, trace, dtrace

As much as I understand from Dtrace docs, it can be very useful in Native-compiled languages (C, C++, D, Haskell, Rust, Go...) since debugging and tracing compiled binary code is difficult in those languages particularly when there is no debug symbol. But AFAIK, debugging dynamic languages is much easier (Since you have the source code) and also debugging runtime based languages (JVM, OTP....) is possible using other methods.
How much value DTrace adds to non-native languages? They all have libraries and packages for DTrace, but I am in doubt it is worth of using them.

Comment: Of course DTrace is useful in those situations. Why do you assume having access to the source code is always useful? Having a steaming pile of horrible spaghetti source code isn't useful unless you know what code is actually being run.  DTrace can easily tell you exactly what code gets run.  DTrace will also be able to tell you exactly what the *interpreter* for your language is doing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes you are right! But my question is still unanswered! Is Dtrace as useful there?